# PostgreSQL: Rename entries that are case sensitive to one

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database, which entries that look like the following:

| twitter_name | unnest |
| --- | --- |
| apple | flower |
| apple | bug |
| banana | bug |
| BANana | flower |
| bAnana | leaf |

The idea is to create a network where all the entries are nodes and column1-nodes connect to column2 nodes. As is evident, the "banana" nodes are case sensitive and when creating the network, I end up with three different nodes instead of just one "banana" node. 
Anyway of changing this? I thought maybe using RegEx to rename and merge but I am not quite sure. 
The query I used to get this table is the following:

```
with cte as (
    select u.twitter_name, REGEXP_MATCHES(t.txt, '@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)', 'g') as mentions
    from tweet as t, twitter_user as u
    where t.author_id = u.id
)
select twitter_name, unnest(mentions)
from cte;
```

Would be grateful for any tips!

Comment: Create a cte and use it as the source for your query:  `with dedup as (select distinct lower(column1) as column1, lower(column2) as column2 from my_table) select <your query goes here> from dedup where <more of your logic>; `

Comment: If you want just one row for banana, fine - but which value of column2 you want to preserve? bug? flower? leaf? Why this value (it will be important for the query that removes "duplicates"

Comment: Please post you actual query, it is difficult to determine necessary change without it. For long run however, the best solution is to *correct* or standardize at insert time. One possibility add another column: `l_column1 text generated always as (lower(column1) ) stored`. Then query l_column1. If necessary do the same with column2.

Comment: @eijeze i dont want to remove duplicates... as you can see i have two apple but in the end when creating my network it will show one node apple linking to two other nodes

Comment: Then sorry, I don't undersntand what you want to do. Perhaps simple: `update table set column1 = lower(column1) where column1 <> lower(column1)` ?

Comment: can you share your output table? @luthienaerendell

Comment: @lemon the output table is the table with the apples and bananas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "*rename entries that are case sensitive to one*", as the title of your post says, instead of working with regex and merging, you can do it with a small change to your original query.

You should change the selection of `twitter_name` to the selection of the lowered `twitter_name`, using the PostgreSQL [`LOWER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) function as follows:

```
with cte as (
    select u.twitter_name, REGEXP_MATCHES(t.txt, '@([A-Za-z0-9_]+)', 'g') as mentions
    from tweet as t, twitter_user as u
    where t.author_id = u.id
)
select LOWER(twitter_name), unnest(mentions)
from cte;
```

Given that the original query works on your data, this fix should allow you to get the fixed table:

| twitter_name | unnest |
| --- | --- |
| apple | flower |
| apple | bug |
| banana | bug |
| banana | flower |
| banana | leaf |